# Reading and handling many small CSV-s to concatenate one large Dataframe

Tags: pandas, database, multithreading, dataframe, parallel-processing

I have two folders each contains about 8,000 small csv files. One with an aggregated size of around 2GB and another with aggregated size of around 200GB.

These files are stored like this to better update them in a daily basis. However, when I conduct EDA, I would like them to be assigned to a single variable. For example.

```
path = "some random path"
df = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f"{path}//{files}") for files in os.listdir(path)])
```

It would take much less time for me to read the dataset with 2GB in total size than reading it on the super computer cluster. And it is impossible to read the 200GB dataset on the local machine unless using some sort of scaling Pandas solutions. The situation does not seem to improve on the cluster even using the popular open-source tools like Dask and Modin.

Is there an effective way that enables to read those csv files effectively with given situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Q :**
> <sub>*"Is there an effective way that enables to read those csv files effectively ... ?"*</sub>

**A :**
Oh, sure, there is :

CSV format ( standard attempts in RFC4180 ) is not unambiguous and is not obeyed under all circumstances ( commas inside fields, header present or not ), so some caution & care is needed here. Given you are your own data curator, you shall be able to decide plausible steps for handling your own data properly.

So, the as-is state is :

```
                                            #                 in <_folder_1_>
::::::::                                    # 8000 CSV-files ~   2GB in total
||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||| # 8000 CSV-files ~ 200GB in total
                                            #                 in <_folder_2_>
```

Speaking efficiency, O/S coreutils provide the best, stable, proven and most efficient (as system tool used to be since ever ) tools for the phase of merging thousands and thousands of plain CSV-files' content :

```
###################### if need be,
######################    use an in-place remove of all CSV-file headers first :
for F in $( ls *.csv ); do sed -i '1d' $F; done
```

this helps for case we cannot avoid headers on the CSV-exporter side. Works like this :

```
(base):~$ cat ?.csv
HEADER
1
2
3
HEADER
4
5
6
HEADER
7
8
9
(base):~$ for i in $( ls ?.csv ); do sed -i '1d' $i; done
(base):~$ cat ?.csv
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Now, the merging phase :

```
###################### join
cat *.csv > __all_CSVs_JOINED.csv
```

Given the nature of the said file storage policy, performance can be boosted by using more processes for independent taking small files and large files separately, as defined above, having put the logic inside a pair of `conversion_script_?.sh` shell-scripts :

```
parallel --jobs 2 conversion_script_{1}.sh ::: $( seq -f "%1g"  1 2 )
```

As the transformation is a "just"-`[CONCURRENT]` flow of processing for a sake of removing the CSV-headers, but a pure-`[SERIAL]` ( for larger number of files, there might become interesting to use a multi-staged tree of trees - using several stages of `[SERIAL]`-collections of `[CONCURRENT]`-ly pre-processed leaves, yet for just 8000 files, not knowing the actual file-system details, the latency-masking from a just-`[CONCURRENT]` processing both of the directories just independently will be fine to start with )

Last but not least, the final pair of `___all_CSVs_JOINED.csv` are safe to get opened using in a way, that prevents moving all disk-stored date into RAM at once ( using chunk-size-fused file-reading-iterator, avoiding RAM-spillovers by using `mmap`ed-mode as a context manager ) :

```
with pandas.read_csv( "<_folder_1_>//___all_CSVs_JOINED.csv",
                       sep        = NoDefault.no_default,
                       delimiter  = None,
                       ...
                       chunksize  = SAFE_CHUNK_SIZE,
                       ...
                       memory_map = True,
                       ...
                       ) \
  as df_reader_MMAPer_CtxMGR:
     ...
```

When tweaking for ultimate performance, details matter and depend on physical hardware bottlenecks ( disk-I/O-wise, filesystem-wise, RAM-I/O-wise ), so due care may take further improvement for minimising the repetitive performed end-to-end processing times ( sometimes even turning data into a compressed/zipped form, in cases, where CPU/RAM resources permit sufficient performance advantages over limited performance of disk-I/O throughput - moving less bytes is so faster, that CPU/RAM-decompression costs are still lower, than moving `200+ [GB]`s of uncompressed plain text data.

Details matter,
tweak [options](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html#pandas.read_csv),
benchmark,
tweak options,
benchmark,
tweak options,
benchmark

> would be nice to post your progress on testing the performance
> end-2-end duration of strategy ... `[s]` AS-IS now
> end-2-end duration of strategy ... `[s]` with parallel --jobs 2 ...
> end-2-end duration of strategy ... `[s]` with parallel --jobs 4 ...
> end-2-end duration of strategy ... `[s]` with parallel --jobs N ... + compression
>  ... keep us posted

Comment: Hi there I appreicate for your answer. However I have some trouble understanding your techniques. Coupld you please explain this idea in more understandable terms? Thank you!

Comment: Always welcome, @KevinLi - lets start [a] post the actual End-to-End processing time it takes now, as you can benchmark how long it takes to process all the ~16k files now, processing 202 GB as-is, before we start changes - ( Have you measured the time already - as you run the task daily? No? So do it today & post it as an update ). [b] Next tell us, how far have you followed the recipe - which first point of the step-wise ( phased ) recipe was not clear or caused some problems to execute in-vivo. [c] Show results/error messages you've tried to debug if exceptions fired. That's fair, isn't it?